# Hid first div with specific content after body tag - no id or classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I have a div that appears on my site from a compiled module which I can't edit. I just want to hide this div for now - eventually the module will be replaced.

The div does not have a classname or id but on the pages it appears on it is the first dv after the body tag and starts out like so

```
<div align="right">
<font size="-2" color="#808080">
Found session:
```

I don't want to inadvertantly hide some other div if it appears on one of the site pages so was hoping there is some way to use the above data - perhaps 'if div contains "Found session:" to make sure it is the right div and hide it. I don't know jquery mostly just use existing script with minor tweaking so would appreciate detailed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('body div').first().filter(':contains("Found session:")').hide()
```

`$('body div').first()` finds the first div within the `body` element and the `filter()` will make sure the element contains the text `Found session:`